# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result to activity {}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am trying to change Button property after taking a picture with the Camera.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        Bitmap bitmap = utilities.decodeFile(path, 300);
        imgPicHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //The pic is changing on the previous Activity, this works fine



        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
         button.setText("NewText");
        //Here is the problem, when trying to change the button property from the previous      activity before taking the picture..



}
```

Comment: create obj of button out of this method.Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange);

Comment: What do you mean by creating an Object? How I will be able to change the property of the button after that? Can you give me some code example?

Comment: Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange); deffind this in your activity. and you can use button.setText() inside the above method.

Comment: `findViewById` will look for the views in the current activity, it will obviously not work if that `Button` is in the previously child activity(which now is dead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is pass this `String` from `Activity2` to `Activity1` via `Intent.putExtra()` and in `Activity1`, use `getIntent().getStringExtra()` to retrive this `string` and then set it as the `Button` text in `Activity1`'s `onResume()`